# fit any image in a preset size of a div

Tags: html, css, image, resize, autolayout

I have some divs set up to display images as links with and im trying to set up a standardized way to place an image in the div and at LEAST have it stretch the image to fit for me. I would really like to be able to adjust the cropping to fit in the square, but i realize that may be a bit tricky.
Heres what i currently have:
(tried to post image but dont have the rep just yet so heres a link https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNRD9.jpg

How would i go about doing this? I thought that using

```
style="height:100%; width:100%"
```

would work, but it still didnt stretch the photo to the maximum height, possibly due to how i have things layed out.
In the photo above, each photo is set up like:

```
<div class="4u 12u$(mobile)">
            <article class="item">
                    <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/resume.jpg" title="My Resume" alt="My Resume" /></a>
                            <header>
                                <h3>My Resume</h3>
                            </header>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Reproduce that in fiddle

Comment: what.....? im confused, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Specifying width and height to `.item` class might fix it.
Please post the css style you have done so far so that we can look into it and suggest changes to achieve your requirement.

Comment: well i dont really have a css style on it, i have the "image fit" class but im not entirely sure what that does specifically (im using a template to do all this). i will try what you suggest and comment back.

Answer (score 1):

A fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/), and a pen (http://codepen.io/), are great ways to present what you are trying to do for other people. You can put your HTML, CSS, and JS, and it will render it for you, for free. Check them out.

You can use `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell` on the div container, `<div>`, and the `<article>` respectively.

Another great solution is using a flexbox, Css Tricks have a great guide on it.

If you are interested in grids and frameworks I will suggest that you check out “Foundation”, or “Bootstrap” or the myriad of other HTML5 frameworks.

Put your code in a fiddle, so we will be able to help you out with your code. Until then, here is a suggestion

```
a{width:auto; display:inline-block; min-height:100px; overflow:hidden;}

img{width:100%;}
```

`Overflow:hidden;` will hide the parts of the `<img/>` that lies outside the bounds of `<a>`

Comment: I like the effort you put in your answer, but try to format your code to improve your answer even more. There are buttons to display your code as actual code in the edit screen.